# Open Redirect Protection

Tags: php, apache, security

[Google's Webmaster blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/01/open-redirect-urls-is-your-site-being.html) wrote some solution on how to prevent Open Redirect Protection abuse, I've been perplexed by some of the solutions there for quite sometime, I tried googling but found no results.

1. Change the redirect code to check the referer
2. Consider using a whitelist
3. Consider signing your redirects
4. Specifically disallow off-site redirects

My guesses on the solution:

1. Use `%{HTTP­_RE­FERER}` to do some checking in the url request
2. Use some regex in the url request to check if the site in the url
   request is within the scope of the regex
3. Can't think of any
4. Can't think of any

Please let me know if my guesses are correct, and if they're not please tell me how to do it correctly in PHP or Apache. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. correct, but this is not a reliable approach. HTTP Referrer can be manipulated.
2. Define a list of URLs which are allowed to be redirected to, compare to this list and cancel redirects to any other URL.
3. Add a salted hash of the redirect as a redirect param. Before redirecting, check that hash with the request params. If the calculated hash is the same as the hash in the request params, probably no request manipulation is made -> redirect can be executed. This prevents any redirects to be executed unless anybody guesses your hash-generation algorithm (thats why you have to salt it with a secret key).
4. Cancel all redirects which will lead to any URL that doesn't contain your website as host. This can be done with a regex as you guessed at 2.

Comment: Because HTTP-Referrer is editable by clients -> ignore it. Or use it as an additional check if if this makes you more happy, but don't rely on it as a security check. How to use a white list? Well $list = array("[URL1]", "[URL2]", ...). Then check with in_array() if the requested redirect target is in this list. If so -> redirect. This is a basic example and can be expanded by additional regex as needed.

Answer (score 0):

An Open Redirect becomes possible when your application does a blind redirect based on user supplied content ie by POST or GET. Open Redirects are most commonly exploited by Phishing attacks.

To prevent Open Redirects, you should validate and verify any URL that you redirect to if the URL is coming from user input. It should be verified based on a whitelist.

Comment: How do I create the whitelist using apache or php?

Comment: @PHPForLife you should create an array of while-list. then iterate through this one using some condition against user input